# What does this number represent in the information about an article?

Tags: journals

> Phys. Rev. B **61**, 14095 – Published 15 May 2000

I am reading something from this publisher for the first time. What do they want to tell us with the number 14095? Is it the number of the page where this article is? How is it possible to have so many pages?

Comment: Yes it is the page; journals have different page numbering strategies, some start over at each issue, some start over at each volume, some number pages from the beginning of the journal. For citations, all that is important is that the page number(plus volume, issue, etc) directs a reader to a particular article.

Comment: @BryanKrause is this common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed a page number, as evidenced by [this overview of the issue](http://journals.aps.org/prb/issues/61#v61) and the fact that that very article’s pages are numbered accordingly.

The reason for this is that Physical Review B is a very big journal and (in 2000) used running page numbers for all articles of an issue, which in turn spanned the entire year.